# react-materialize SideNav & trigger placement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

I've been working on a website and trying to use the SidNav from [react-materialize](https://react-materialize.github.io/#/sidenav). I have a router with two component being rendered :

```
<Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={NavBar} />
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    </div>
  </Router>
```

I want to put the trigger button form NavBar in the Home component.

```
<SideNav
    trigger={<Button>SIDE NAV DEMO</Button>}
    options={{ closeOnClick: true }}
  >

  </SideNav>
```

I want to reuse the sidebar in multiple component, How could I do that ?

Comment: go to Home and simply paste the code (<sideNav></sideNav)there? .. will this not solve your problem

Comment: Yes, but I want to reuse the side bar on other places

Comment: do you mean the same code which you write in sideNav for Home component should also be used by  other component

Comment: Yes, the sidenav should be accessible on every other pages

Comment: below i have written some code put you sidenav react material in one custom compnent say Resuableside nav.. and import in  your HOME compoent or DASHBOARD component etc hope this helps you

Comment: Oh yes I was thinking the wrong way round ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may write you code like this

**ResusableSideNav.js**

```
import 'react' from 'React'
import sideNave from 'react/materialcomponent'

class ResusableSideNav extends React.component {
    render(){
        return(
            <SideNav
                trigger={<Button></Button>}
                options={{ closeOnClick: true }}
            >
                <SideNavItem userView
                        user={{
                        background: 'img/office.jpg',
                        image: 'img/yuna.jpg',
                        name: this.Prop1.value,
                        email: this.Prop2.value
                    }}
                />
            </SideNav>
        )
    }
}
```

**Home.js**

```
import 'react' from 'React'
import ResuableSideNav from the "address where you worte"

class Home extends React.Component {
    render(){
        <ResuableSideNav prop1={value} {...otherProps}/>
    }
}
```